# Can I use GitHub API to extract the events of 'used by' of a repository?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v4

GitHub supports [listing the projects that depend on a repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/listing-the-projects-that-depend-on-a-repository). Can I extract the events (e.g. time) of these dependencies by GitHub API? If not, how can I get this information?

Comment: I guess you'd have to look for the commits that introduced the dependency, but that might not be easy to automate.

Comment: I think so. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

GitHub API v4 supports this feature in "preview" as of April 2018: https://developer.github.com/v4/previews/#access-to-a-repositories-dependency-graph.

I tried the following query, but the results seem strange to me.

```
{
    repository(owner:"tensorflow", name:"tensorflow") {
        dependencyGraphManifests{
            totalCount
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
{'data': {'repository': {'dependencyGraphManifests': {'totalCount': 14}}}}
```

I tried to know why the `totalCount` is 14, so I run the following statments:

```
{
    repository(owner:"tensorflow", name:"tensorflow") {
        dependencyGraphManifests{
            edges{
              node{
                repository{
                 name
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
{'data': {'repository': {'dependencyGraphManifests': {'edges': [{'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}, {'node': {'repository': {'name': 'tensorflow'}}}]}}}}
```

Can anyone know why?